# Reference to image built by docker compose is tied to project/directory name

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to set up a drupal environment with docker compose and it is working somewhat.

However, I've split my image up in a base drupal image and a custom layer on top with my configuration, modules and so on. The base image is pulled from the official repo and enhanced with a couple of tools I need (for example composer and a php extension).

My dockerfile for the custom layer looks like this (first few lines):

```
FROM reponame_drupal

COPY sites /var/www/html/sites/
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/sites/default/files
```

(I'm aware that I should probably change permissions with an entrypoint script)

This works since everything is placed in a directory called 'repo-name', however this seems incredibly fragile. If I change the name of my project for some reason my *dockerfiles* breaks.

I would very much like to just write `FROM drupal` or a custom name that I control, instead of one based on the directory name.

Can I change the name of the network to something I can control in code (in docker-compose.yml)? What is the best practice here?

---

The dockerfile for the drupal base looks like this:

```
FROM drupal:7.56-apache

# Install packages
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    curl \
    wget \
    vim \
    git \
    unzip \
    libmcrypt-dev

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    mcrypt

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    ln -s /root/.composer/vendor/bin/drush /usr/local/bin/drush

# Install Drush
RUN composer global require drush/drush:8 && \
    composer global update

# Clean repository
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

The docker-compose.yml looks something like this:

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    [additional settings]

  drupal:
    build: ./docker/drupal

  customlayer:
    build: ./docker/customlayer
    ports:
      - "8090:80"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: always

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    [additional settings]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify image option for services you want to build in docker-compose.yml:

```
drupal:
  build: ./docker/drupal
  image: reponame_drupal # or whatever you like
```

Although having this in docker-compose.yml just to build base image for the real service sounds wrong.

Comment: This certainly works. What would you recommend doing differently. Build the image with a command and omit it from the compose file? I like the convenience in having it all in a script, but I'm new to docker so I don't know the pitfalls.

Comment: yes, maybe separate base image build from docker-compose.yml or combine that base image and actual service image. Docker supports nowadays also [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/) but not sure how that might fit to your use case.